# Writing a program to calculate the distinct values of a function

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, discrete-mathematics, wolframalpha

`$$f_n(x)=\pi(x)\pi(n-x)$$`

I want to write a program that tells me the distinct values of `$f_n(x)$` for each $n=2,3,4,...,N$ where `$\pi(x)$` is the prime counting function. Here are the first few distinct values:

S={0,0,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,4,5,4,6,5,7,5,8,5,7,5,8,7,...}.

How can I write such a program?

I tried using Mathematica, wolfram alpha, and R but couldn't figure out how to make the software tell me the distinct values of `$f_n(x).$`

I have no idea how to solve this problem using a computer program so I manually put the first 70 values of n into wolfram alpha one at a time and counted the number of distinct values by looking at the plots. This is what I was able to get so far:

The original prime counting function is in light green and my function is in light blue: (here I've plotted n on the x-axis and the distinct values on the y-axis)

[image]

Here's an example of n=9 corresponding to the two horizontal lines that correspond to the two distinct values for the function:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the attempts that you’ve made so far? I’m curious what you’ve tried and whether you’re actually really close to having a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, you need the package `primes` and then can define your prime-count function $\pi(x)$ as below:

```
PIx <- Vectorize(function(x) length(generate_primes(max = x)),vectorize.args = "x")
```

For instance, given an input vector `v<-c(0,1,4.5,6.1,10)`, then `PIx(v)` gives:

```
> PIx(v)
[1] 0 0 2 3 4
```

Then for your function $f_n(x)$, it can be defined as:

```
PIx <- Vectorize(function(x) length(generate_primes(max = x)),vectorize.args = "x")
f_n <- function(n) unique(PIx(0:n)*PIx(n-(0:n)))
```

To see the distinct values when varying $n$, you apply the code `Filter(length,sapply(2:n, function(k) f_n(k)))`, for example:

```
n <- 15
z <- unlist(Map(length,Filter(length,sapply(2:n, function(k) f_n(k)))))-1
```

which gives a list of distinct levels:

```
> z
 [1] 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 2 4 3 4 3 5 4
```

Comment: n is a constant. And the distinct values of f are calculated for ever natural number n starting with 2

Comment: @Ultradark I guess what you mean is that, in $f_n(x)=\pi(x)\pi(n-x)$ `x=2` while `n = 2,3,4,.....`, am I right?

Comment: why should $x=2$?

Comment: @Ultradark I get a bit confused in your description.....but I will update my solution shortly to see if that is the expected result

Comment: did you see the picture I added to my post? for n=9 you get 2 distinct values for f_9(x)

Comment: @Ultradark I see, but what is the value for `x`? Given a fixed `n`, but you need `x` to get $\pi(n-x)$

Comment: hmm, maybe for a fixed n you would need to test all the values of x to see which ones yield distinct heights? So maybe it would be possible to calculate all heights of the function and then throw out duplicate values? And then do that for each n?

Comment: @Ultradark, I changed my code to show distinct levels for when varying `n`, please check it out. By the way, is `0` counted as a level in your output? In my code, I just assume that all levels should be greater than zero.

Comment: 0 is not counted as a level, but help me understand that last line?

Comment: Is that all the distinct levels up to n=15?

Comment: one more problem I'm having: R can't seem to find the function "generate_primes" even though I installed the package "primes"

Comment: @Ultradark Yes, it is up to `n=15`. What is your version of `R`? Mine is `R 3.6.1`. You need to load the package first, i.e., `library(primes)`. Also, try with `primes::generate_primes()`

Answer (score 1):

Further to your clarification

```
f[n_, x_] := PrimePi[x]*PrimePi[n - x]

green = {#, PrimePi[#]} & /@ Range[2, 70];

blue = Map[Function[n,
   {n, Length[DeleteCases[Union[f[n, #] & /@ Range[2, 70]], 0]]}],
  Range[2, 70]];

ListPlot[{blue, green}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, AxesLabel -> {"n", None},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 20}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.6, AspectRatio -> 2/7, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Note there are differences from the OP's plot at `n = 60, 61`.  Perhaps the OP miscounted.

Comment: x is the variable in the function and n is the parameter. So for each n I calculate the distinct values of f. So for n=9 there are two distinct values